# How to create a path to a file resource (e.g. JSON) in a portlet?

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

I am trying to use the `i18next` package in a Liferay portlet. The initialisation requires a path to the translation files.

The path to the resources normally looks something like `js/locales/__lng__/__ns__.json`. (The `i18next` package substitutes some values and makes an AJAX call to fetch the JSON file.)

In Liferay, I tried using the simple relative path as described above but this didn't work.

```
myportlet
 +-js
    +-script.js
    +-locales
       +-de
          +-translation.json
       +-en
          +-translation.json
```

Why doesn't the relative path work?
Can I create an absolute path? How would I do that?